# How can I align two asp.net textboxes beside each other with Bootstrap?

Tags: asp.net, twitter-bootstrap

I want to have the two text boxes below Account to be align horizontally. I've tried using different amounts of columns but I cannot seem to get them to change from being stacked on top of each other. I have a link to a prototype that I quickly made it Adobe Xd of how I want the textboxes to look.

This is what I have:

[image]

This is what I want it to look like:

[image]

This is the code i have right now

```html
<div class="form-group">   
  <asp:Label ID="lblwk_num" runat="server" AssociatedControlID="txtwk_num" Text="Work Order #"  CssClass=""></asp:Label>
  <asp:TextBox ID="txtwk_num" runat="server"  ReadOnly="True"  CssClass="form-control" Enabled="False"></asp:TextBox>
</div>

<div class ="form-group">
  <asp:Label ID="lblwk_acct" runat="server" AssociatedControlID="txtwk_acct" Text="Account" ></asp:Label>
  <asp:TextBox ID="txtwk_acct" ReadOnly="True"  Enabled="False" CssClass="form-control" runat="server" ></asp:TextBox>
  <asp:TextBox ID="txtwk_suffix" runat="server"  CssClass="form-control"  ReadOnly="True" Enabled="False"></asp:TextBox>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used form-inline class and I got the text boxes side by side. Find the attached sample output. Accept my answer if it works for you.

However there could be a better approach. Will post here if I found any.

[image]

```
<div class="form-group">   
  <asp:Label ID="lblwk_num" runat="server" AssociatedControlID="txtwk_num" Text="Work Order #"  CssClass=""></asp:Label>
  <asp:TextBox ID="txtwk_num" runat="server"  ReadOnly="True"  CssClass="form-control" Enabled="False"></asp:TextBox>
</div>

  <asp:Label ID="lblwk_acct" runat="server" AssociatedControlID="txtwk_acct" Text="Account" ></asp:Label>
<div class="form-inline">
        <div class="form-group">
  <asp:TextBox ID="txtwk_acct" ReadOnly="True"  Enabled="False" CssClass="form-control" runat="server" ></asp:TextBox>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
  <asp:TextBox ID="txtwk_suffix" runat="server"  CssClass="form-control"  ReadOnly="True" Enabled="False"></asp:TextBox>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: This seemed to do exactly what I was looking for.  Thanks for the help.